# Magento Products are not listed on frontend

Tags: magento-1.5

I downloaded an old **magento version 1.5** and installed it on my local server.

My admin panel is working perfect but products are not listed in frontend.

Links are not working on frontend.

I have cleared **cache, reindexed data, increased memory_limit.**

Nothing is working for me, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue of htaccess file
so delete or rename the .htaccess file
after go to

`admin panel > system > configuration > web > Use Web Server Rewrites choose **No**`

and in

`secure tab Use Secure URLs in Frontend select **No**`

then check I hope its work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with `mod_rewrite` mode in your local apache.

You have to enable `mode_rewrite` in your apache.

You can follow below question and try solution for enabling the `mode_rewrite` in your local server.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

If you are using **IIS** then you can download this and install in your IIS for `mod_rewrite`

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

If you are using **WAMP** Then also look at the below answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152016/mod-rewrite-on-wamp-2-4

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391530/how-to-use-htaccess-in-wamp-server#answer-6397585